# Where is exactly Pygame installed on my PC?

Tags: python, pygame

I have recently installed Pygame on Windows 10 using pip (confirmed the installation by running: `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens`). I couldn't find any directories with Pygame on my computer.  I found the built-in modules of Python in its installation directory but not Pygame's.

Where are the different Python packages installed if they're not in the installation directory, and specifically where are Pygame's?

Comment: try `python -c 'import pygame; print(pygame.__file__)'`

Comment: You did not specify important information, such as OS :-)
(with linux or Mac, I would have used `locate pygame`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My pygame file location was:

`C:\Users\*YourUsername*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python37-32\Scripts`

However you need to change your username and you may have to change it for which Python install you have

Answer (score 0):

Using a Windows machine, you can use a suggestion above except use double quotes in place of the single quotes:

`python -c "import pygame; print(pygame.__file__)"`

Using this command I found the pygame package installed on my machine at:

`C:\Users\*YourUsername*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\`